# Error using sudo -stdin

Tags: sudo, echo

I'm trying to use the -S stdin arg on sudo.

I tried this:

```
echo 'mypass' | sudo -S cat /etc/shadow
```

And

```
echo 'mypass\n' | sudo -S cat /etc/shadow
```

As the man pages suggest to add a newline.

Both won't work. What is wrong?

Comment: By the way, this is a *horrible* security risk. Your password is now stored in plaintext in `~/.bash_history`.

Comment: I'm aware of this. But I see no other method for 'no prompt' sudoing.

Comment: You can set it up to be passwordless (which is, obviously, not a good way to increase security) or you can write the password into a file only you can read and pass the file's contents to `sudo`. This is, again, not perfect, but t least it won't be in the history file. Alternatively, you run things as root in an `sudo -i` session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo` command won't print newlines with the `\n` sequence. Use `printf` instead.

```
printf "mypassword\n" | sudo -S cat /etc/shadow
```

Comment: I just tested. It didn't work. But then I changed my password to something more simple, and it dit work. Odd.

Comment: Probably you have shell metachars in your password, consider wrapping your password in single quotes rather than double quotes to prevent parsing of metachars.

Comment: The OP was already using single quotes. And the `echo` prints a newline by default, so there's no need for two. @MathiasMaes does your password contain the character `'`? That would break what you are attempting.

Comment: My password doesn't contain ' no. I just tested it again. I changed my password to 'testpassword' without quotes. I tried this:
printf 'testpassword\n' | sudo -S chpasswd < <( echo 'magjefzuzkfnkbexqgxcjnkju:thisisatest' )
[sudo] password for mathias: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for mathias: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt

Comment: Even weirder!!!
It actually does work for sudo -S cat /etc/shadow
But it doesn't for chpasswd for example!

Comment: @MathiasMaes As you are providing input from two places (the pipe `|` and shell redirect `<<`), the input is taken from the second place, not the first. You may correct it by wrapping around brackets: `(printf 'testpassword\n' | sudo -S chpasswd) << (echo 'magjefzuzkfnkbexqgxcjnkju:thisisatest')`

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar thanks for your help. Your explanation sounds very logical. Altough that throws an error:

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Am a newbie too, but I think you may add a space between those `<`'s like this: `(commands) < <(echo newpassword)`